# AWS CodeArtifactory - Request failed \"401 Unauthorized\"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-codeartifact

I have nodeJs project which use AWS CodeArtifact. One script populate .npmrc file and I have a proper registry and _authToken there. Everything works properly.

Recently my colleague added new branch which suppose to upgrade node version form 12 to 16. When I use this branch I can't go through my regular flow and have:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "<***registry url***>/infinity-logger/-/infinity-logger-0.13.1.tgz: Request failed \"401 Unauthorized\"".
```

The error appears when I run "yarn install". I didn't find in new branch anything related to CodeArtifact. How to debag it? Why same command (yarn install) works for one branch and doesn't work for another?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.